# How to pass data from React component to node server.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to pass data from my React component to the node server.js.
In my React component, inside the componentWillMount, I am making an axios post call and pass countValue.

Here is my code for the React Component:

```
componentWillMount = () => {

    axios.post("/", {
      countValue: 12
    });
  }
```

Inside my server.js, I am simply trying to get countValue through req.body.countValue. However, it is always set to "undefined".

req.body just comes out to be empty object, {}.

Here is my code for the server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const engines = require('consolidate');
const app = express();

app.engine("ejs", engines.ejs);
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.countValue);
    res.render("index");
});
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: do you have something like `app.use(express.json())` or `app.use(bodyparser.json())` (needs `body-parser` package)

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Thank you for asking. Yes I do have them. I have updated my code. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: `axios.post("/", {` probably require full uri including scheme (like http or https etc) like: `axios.post("http://localhost:port" ...`)

Answer (score 4):

you are making POST request with axios from the frontend,

and configured in the server to listen to GET only...

in the express add:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.countValue);
    res.render("index");
});
```

very strange... i tested it and it working,

if you making small app without the react ... it's working?

this is the full test that worked for me:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('so');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("countValue =", req.body.countValue);
    res.render('so');
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('app now listening on port 3000');
});
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SO</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    axios.post("/", {
        countValue: 12
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added above code in my server.js file. But it doesn't even get to that console.log in the app.post.. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: i made edit after testing it... clean and small app without react. please check if it's working for ...